# How to change a property field in a xml file with java

Tags: java, xml

I hava an xml file in the hard disk.I want at run-time my java application to change a property of the xml file.I just wondering which is the fastest and more lighter procedure?
1)parse the xml file with DOM
2)set the property value in a new document in memory
3)write the new document with the new property value back in the same file.
That is what i am thinking now.Is there any way to avoid step 3 and just load the xml and change the value?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

On alternative is to specify the property change as an XSL transform and run it using one of the Java XSLT implementations.

Comment: That probably depends on the XSLT implementation ... and the exact nature of the transformation.

Comment: can you be more specific?i just want to change an element content